# Firebase not initialized in Vue3 Router

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-cli-3

I initialize firebase in main.js and it works overall in the application.

When I use a firebase in the router for the `beforeEnter` checks it doesn't recognize that firebase has been initialized.

exception: `Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app/no-app).`

Looking at logs, the router `beforeEnter` check is done before main.js where the init is done.

main.js:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user){...}
```

router.ts:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  console.log("router | beforeEach")
  const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth);

  if(requiresAuth && (!currentUser || currentUser.isAnonymous)) next('login')
  else if(!requiresAuth && currentUser) next('eorDashboard')
  else next();
})
```

How to bypass this issue as it was working well in Vue2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `main.js`, you should make sure only init Vue application when Firebase Auth object is ready to use

**main.js**

```
let app = ''

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(() => {
  if (!app) {
    app = new Vue({
      router,
      render: h => h(App)
    }).$mount('#app')
  }
})
```